# Git cannot allocate enough memory to install Homebrew

Tags: linux, git, error-handling, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install Homebrew on Linux on a cluster. But I am constantly getting the following error messages:

```
fatal: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-9d2d97f367d3ebfa65a3b708b2d87333a8eb2bf0.pack cannot be mapped: Cannot allocate memory

error: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core did not send all necessary objects

Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I then created a `.git` repository using the `git init` command on the `.linuxbrew` folder.

Can you please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Zelnox/210419 — perhaps can pull the repo as an archive?

Comment: How do you run this script? like bash "script.rb"?

Comment: Just `./script.rb` should suffice if it’s +x. It uses Ruby, per the shebang line so `ruby script.rb` should also work. YMMV. Make sure to read the content of internet scripts first :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As I see it is written `/usr/local/`. So I will have to change it to the `/blah/blah/blah/.linuxbrew`, right?

Answer (score 1):

From the message it looks like git is trying to memory map the entire given file and running out of physical memory. You might want to add more virtual memory to your sistem. It will be slower but there is a chance it will proceed forward.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation

Comment: Thank you. But the thing is that I am trying to install homebrew on an external server connected through `ssh` where I am not permitted to run `sudo` or increase memory by myself.

Comment: @AnikDutta is it running out of disk space by any chance? Did you reach your quota on that server?

Comment: No, I checked that there is enough memory using the command `ps aux --sort -rss`. It does not look like the case.